# Grid RowDefinintion fixed Height ignored

Tags: wpf, grid-layout, rowdefinition

I have a simple Grid with two rows, the first having a fixed height. Inside, I have an element with RowSpan="2", and on top another element which should reside only in the first row:

```
        <Grid Background="Lime">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Rectangle Grid.RowSpan="2" Height="50" Fill="Blue"/>

            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="Foo" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="Red"/>
        </Grid>
```

However, the actualheigth of the first row simply ignores the Height setting, beeing much larger than expected.

Is this a bug in the Grid? How can I workaround this?

Comment: No Bug, works as expected, what do you mean by "actualheigth of the first column" ? I dont see any column in code... try to draw a layout that you want to get with this snippet, it will help to understand question

Comment: Sorry, I meant "first row" (corrected). I expect that the first row is 20 pixels high, but it is 35 (depending on the height of the rectangle, which is not fixed in the real case)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
<Grid Background="Lime">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Rectangle Grid.RowSpan="2" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Center" Fill="Blue"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="Foo" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="Red"/>
</Grid>
```

I'm not sure if having a `RowSpan` that covers a `RowDefinition` with `Height="*"` would work out.

Comment: Thanks, but the height of the item with `RowSpan="2"` is not fixed (depending on its actual content) in my real application. So this does not work in my case.

Comment: Ah, well then try `"Auto"` for the second `RowDefinition` (updated answer to match) ... as another commenter said, it would help to see expected layout, but I think this might get you closer.

Comment: No, it makes the second column collapse, so that the first column has the whole height...

Answer (score 0):

i also tried this a few times, but it won't work. I think it's by design. Can't you just put the rectangle as a parent of the grid in the xaml?

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem to work this way
Instead, I simply used the `VerticalAlignment` property to move the `TextBlock` to the top, and completely removed the RowDefinitions:

```
        <Grid Background="Lime">
            <Rectangle Height="50" Fill="Blue"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="Foo" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="Red" Height="20"/>
        </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you must use VerticalAlignment to stretch in order to fill your RowDefinition's Height.

```
<Grid Background="Lime">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Rectangle Grid.RowSpan="2" Height="50" Fill="Blue"/>

    <TextBlock Name="texto" Grid.Row="0" Text="Foo" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Red"/>
</Grid>
```

On this way you will see your TextBox stretched to the Row height.